# Написать обобщенный метод для фильтрации?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Хочу сделать обобщенную функцию для поиска определенного вписанного слова в uri.

```
public static class SortingExtension
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, object>> ToLambda<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        var parametr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
        var property = Expression.Property(parametr, propertyName);
        var propObject = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object));

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(propObject, parametr);
    }

    public static IQueryable<T> ApplyOrdering<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, 
        string propertyName, bool desc = false)
    {
        return desc != true ?
            source.OrderBy(ToLambda<T>(propertyName))
            : source.OrderByDescending(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Теперь не пойму как мне переделать из этого метода-сортировки в метод-поиска =>

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplySorting<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    string propertyName, string input)
{ 
    return source ????

}
```

Comment: Скажите, а код, тот что рабочий, вы писали, понимаете как оно работает? Если да, то вопрос весьма странный, ваша задача проще, чем та что вы решили ранее, а если нет, то не желаете ли сначала разобраться? Или вам просто нужно кем-то написанное готовое решение, просто чтобы работало?

Comment: Вы хотите что-то типа `return source.Where(x => x.Brand.Contains(target));` но с указанием произвольного поля для фильтрации а не конкретное поле Brand, да? Типа вот так использовать: `source.Filter(x => x.Brand, "Bentley").ToArray();`, верно понимаю вопрос?

Comment: Да я понимаю, что я написал, и да функция - рабочая. Работает для сортировки, а вот для поиска - не понимаю как мне работать с деревом выражения. 
 return source.Where(ToLambda<T>(propertyName));  - ошибка "cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T, object>>' to 'System.Func<T, bool>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот метод для фильтрации, позволяющий задать имя свойства и значение.
Сравнение происходит по равенству: `==`.
Для указания операций "больше", "меньше" и т. п можно добавить третий параметр.

```
public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(this IQueryable<T> source,
    string propertyName, object value)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var memberAccess = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, propertyName);
    var exprRight = Expression.Constant(value);
    var equalExpr = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, exprRight);

    Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(equalExpr, parameter);

    return source.Where(lambda);
}
```

А можно взять библиотеку Dynamic LINQ, в которой уже реализовано подобное.

Answer (score 0):

Обобщенная функция для поиска по полю.

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetColumnEquality<T>(string property, string term)
{
    var obj = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var objProperty = Expression.PropertyOrField(obj, property);
    var objEquality = Expression.Equal(objProperty, Expression.Constant(term));

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(objEquality, obj);
}

public static IQueryable<T> ApplyFiltering<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, string propertyLabel, string search)
{
    var propertyName = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                      .Where(e => e.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                      .Where(property => property.Name == propertyLabel)
                      .Select(x => x.Name).ToList();

    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();

    foreach (var name in propertyName)
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(GetColumnEquality<T>(name, search));
    }

    return source.Where(predicate);
}
```